# MySQL table alias does not work

Tags: mysql, sql, table-alias

So I am using 'as' command in this code

```
select PERSONAL_ID,NAME,SURNAME,BIRTH_DATE,NUMBER_OF_ORDERS  
from(
select PERSONAL_ID,NAME,SURNAME,BIRTH_DATE,count(CUSTOMER_ID) as NUMBER_OF_ORDERS
from customer as C
right join
customer_hotel as CH on CH.CUSTOMER_ID = C.ID
group by(CH.CUSTOMER_ID)
) as O
where NUMBER_OF_ORDERS = (select max(NUMBER_OF_ORDERS) from O);
```

and it says: Table 'company.o' doesn't exist.
but when I do it like this

```
select PERSONAL_ID,NAME,SURNAME,BIRTH_DATE,NUMBER_OF_ORDERS  
from(
select PERSONAL_ID,NAME,SURNAME,BIRTH_DATE,count(CUSTOMER_ID) as NUMBER_OF_ORDERS
from customer as C
right join
customer_hotel as CH on CH.CUSTOMER_ID = C.ID
group by(CH.CUSTOMER_ID)
) as O
where NUMBER_OF_ORDERS = (select max(NUMBER_OF_ORDERS) 
from(
select PERSONAL_ID,NAME,SURNAME,BIRTH_DATE,count(CUSTOMER_ID) as NUMBER_OF_ORDERS
from customer as C
right join
customer_hotel as CH on CH.CUSTOMER_ID = C.ID
group by(CH.CUSTOMER_ID)
) as O);
```

it works properly. any suggestions?

Comment: Sorry, but I think this whole thing is a bit of a mess (including the bit that you think 'works properly'). See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @CGritton yes. it is

Comment: @CGritton not really, it works only if only one row exists with maximum value, but if there are 3 rows with maximum it will only return one.

Comment: @GiorgiCercvadze, ah, gotcha. What you are doing makes sense then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assigning an alias to a subquery doesn't mean it can be treated exactly like a table.

In the first query, mysql has no way to know that the `O` in `select max(NUMBER_OF_ORDERS) from O` isn't a table. So that's how it treats it, hence the error.

Is `company` is the name of your schema?

BTW, perhaps you could return the same information using:

```
select PERSONAL_ID,NAME,SURNAME,BIRTH_DATE,count(CUSTOMER_ID) as NUMBER_OF_ORDERS
from customer as C
right join
customer_hotel as CH on CH.CUSTOMER_ID = C.ID
group by(CH.CUSTOMER_ID)
order by count(CUSTOMER_ID) desc
limit 1;
```